# Getting log of why Android app is moved from foreground to background

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I have an app that is running on a kiosk.  After about 8 hours, the app "goes away".  By "goes away" I mean that it is no longer the top most application and that the desktop shows.  The app is still running though because it appears after I click the "switch applications" button.

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.  I added

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("here", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

protected void onPause() {
    Log.e("here", "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}


protected void onStop() {
    Log.e("here", "onStop");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("here", "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                    };
                }
        );
```

I was thinking this way when I take a bug report I will see what is happening.  However, none of the stuff is appearning in the log.

```
10-31 18:44:03.400   354   397 W InputDispatcher: channel '41327498 com.here/com.here.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-31 18:44:03.400   354   397 E InputDispatcher: channel '41327498 com.here/com.here.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-31 18:44:03.400   354   607 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{41327498 u0 com.here/com.here.MainActivity}
10-31 18:44:03.420   354   607 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41327498 com.here/com.here.MainActivity (server)'
10-31 18:44:03.430   354   366 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{411eea18 u0 com.here/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
10-31 18:44:03.490   354   413 I qtaguid : Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10054) res=-1 errno=1
10-31 18:44:03.490   354   413 W NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10054, 0) failed with errno -1
10-31 18:44:03.600   354   366 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.launcher for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: pid=7147 uid=10024 gids={50024, 1028}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the window is being hidden after around  hours of usage?  Is there something I can instrument the system with to figure this out?

Comment: Since you are eating the exception with your `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, you could be crashing and not knowing. Please log something in `uncaughtException()`.

Comment: The first line of your log `Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!` and `WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{41327498 u0 com.here/com.here.MainActivity}` means that your app crashed, so definitely follow @CommonsWare's comment and log the exception in your handler.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks for the suggestion!  I added a line to log in uncaughtException but still nothing is showing up after the app is moved to the background. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Kai  Thanks for the suggestion!  I added a line to log in uncaughtException but still nothing is showing up after the app is moved to the background. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then I guess you can monitor the app's memory usage, see if it grows steadily

Comment: @kai The memory is becoming big over time.  Shouldn't `onDestroy` or the exception handler be called first before the app is moved away from foreground?

Comment: @Alexis it probably means your app crashed from memory leak with OutOfMemoryException, so no onDestroy will not be called, but you should see it in your exception handler though. Regardless, what you should try to do now is to fix the leak.

Comment: @Kai Thanks for the info.  I'm using a webView with a ton of animations in js/css.  I tried adding `onLowMemory(){webView.clearCache(true);}` but it didn't help.  Is there a way to catch this exception and save the app before it dies?  Or a better way to handle the webView leaking memory?

Comment: @Alexis I suggest do a quick test first, by periodically finishing the Activity with the WebView and starting a few instance every hour, to see if the problem is fix. If this does fix the issue then decide how to best manage memory used by WebView.